# Testcafe deeply equality fails when a css formatted string is compared with a normally constructed string

Tags: css, testing, jestjs, testcafe

Trying to compare two sentences (deep equal) with one of them having been created with the help of some css formatting fails. The string I want to compare did have a couple of space separators added with

```
  .space:after {
    content: " ";
  }
```

the following are the statements:

```
stmt1 = 'this is the text'
stmt2 = 'this<span className="space"></span>is the<span className="space"></span>text'
```

on the UI both appear identical. But when the tests are run in testcafe `stmt2` appears as 'thisis thestring'

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is not related to TestCafe. CSS pseudo elements like `:before` and `:after` are not parts of the DOM, so their content is not included in the `textContent` property. You can try to implement some custom solution using [ClientFunction](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402789/reference/test-api/clientfunction/constructor#header).